# Accessing member functions in a vector of vectors of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have a pointer to 2d vector of type `cell`:

```
<vector<vector<cell> > *vec;
```

How do I access `cell`'s member functions? I have tried:

```
vec[x][y].get();
```

and:

```
vac[x][y]->get();
```

But neither works, and google isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vec` is a pointer, so

```
(*vec)[x][y].get();
```

or

```
vec->operator[](x)[y].get();
```

You have to ask yourself *why* you have a pointer to a vector.

Comment: I have a vector of objects that all need to read an object their parent holds, that gets updated constantly, so they need a pointer to that object, which is the 2d vector.